# Scroll sprite element on a path

Tags: jquery

I would like to do something similar with: [this](http://benthebodyguard.com/index.php) but instead of a straight path, I have a path with curves!
And the sprites must be able to be animated on scroll!
Any suggestions or help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This JQuery plugin is for creating dynamic character and background animation in pure HTML and JavaScript [spritely.net](http://www.spritely.net/)

This should help you !

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! I saw the library, but I'm worried about adapting the animation to be on scroll, like on the example I provided!